VSCode Disable layout
When I'm on VSCode I have a layout that adds this, I don't know if it's an extension or my theme that does it or simply a VSC option. Does anyone know how to remove the visibility of the layout which makes me see the first lines while I am further down in the code?


This is sticky scroll setting:

You can toggle it on/off separately for Editor, Workbench, and Terminal.

please try to check if the question is a duplicate before answering.
